# Laravel PHP Unit test. Smiliar tests but one fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

These 2 tests are for the password reset. I'm using the basic auth that came out of the box with Laravel. The first test is failing. The second test is passing. They are very similar. I don't understand why the first test is failing.

In the first test:

1. I'm creating a user.
2. Getting a password reset token
3. Making a post request to change my password using the correct data.
4. It keeps telling me I have an error with my email. I don't understand why.

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Tests\Controllers\Unit;

   use Tests\TestCase;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

   class ResetPasswordTest extends TestCase
   {

       use RefreshDatabase;


       // This test is currently failing. It's saying I have error with email.

       public function test_does_change_a_users_password()
       {
           // Create user 
           $user = factory('App\User')->create();

           // This post route creates a new password reset token and stores it into the database.
           $this->post(route('password.email'), ['email' => $user->email]);

           // I get the token
           $token = DB::table('password_resets')->whereEmail($user->email)->first()->token;

           $this->from(route('password.reset', $token));

           // Change password with the correct data
           $response = $this->post('password/reset', [
               'token'                 => $token,
               'email'                 => $user->email,
               'password'              => 'password',
               'password_confirmation' => 'password'
           ]);

           // This is true... It tells me I have an error with my email.
           $reponse->assertSessionHasErrors('email');

           // This is false. The password is not changed to the new password.
           $this->assertTrue(Hash::check('password', $user->fresh()->password));
       }


       // This test is the working one.

       public function test_does_change_a_users_password2()
       {
           $user = factory('App\User')->create();

           $token = Password::createToken($user);
           $new_password = 'bestpassword99';

           DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
               'token'   => $token,
               'email'   => $user->email,
           ]);

           $this->from(route('password.reset', $token));

           $response = $this->post('password/reset', [
               'token'                 => $token,
               'email'                 => $user->email,
               'password'              => $new_password,
               'password_confirmation' => $new_password
           ]);


           $this->assertTrue(Hash::check($new_password, $user->fresh()->password));
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: How do you validate method that takes care of updating password?

Comment: Why your second test is not annotated with `@test` ?

Comment: It's annotated with @test so that you don't have to put test in the function name for it to run.

Comment: No entirely on topic, but these are integration tests and in no way unit tests. If you would turn on code coverage in this test, you'd see that you were hitting pretty much the entire core Laravel framework. That is NOT the idea of a unit test. A unit test would be to create a user and check if it exists.

Comment: @johhnysiver did you read what I wrote? Like carefully.

Comment: I'm using the default auth that came with Laravel @kysilk. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that in when i copy pasted the code to stackoverflow. I re-added it.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the response with `dd($response)` you can see that Laravel complains about the token being invalid.

But why? - Laravel does not store the exact token in the database. It stores a hash of the token. This is to ensure that someone who gained read access to the database cannot (easily) reset user passwords.

So instead of getting the hash from the database you want to get the token that is send to the user.

Let's try to extract the token from the notification:

```
$bag = new \stdClass();

Notification::assertSentTo($user, \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword::class, function ($notification) use ($bag) {
    $bag->token = $notification->token;
    return true;
});

$token = $bag->token;
```

And put it in your test:

```
/** @test */
public function does_change_a_users_password()
{
    Notification::fake();

    // Create user
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    // This post route creates a new password reset token and stores it into the database.
    $this->post(route('password.email'), ['email' => $user->email]);

    // get the password reset token
    $bag = new \stdClass();
    Notification::assertSentTo($user, ResetPassword::class, function ($notification) use ($bag) {
        $bag->token = $notification->token;
        return true;
    });
    $token = $bag->token;

    $this->from(route('password.reset', $token));

    // Change password with the correct data
    $response = $this->post('password/reset', [
        'token'                 => urlencode($token),
        'email'                 => $user->email,
        'password'              => 'password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'password'
    ]);

    //$response->assertSessionHasErrors('password');

    // Ensure password is changed.
    $this->assertTrue(Hash::check('password', $user->fresh()->password));
}
```